Skip Dropdown button in Primeng Autocomplete when pressing Tab
I am using primeng to use multiple autocompletes with dropdown in my Angular reactive form. The autocompletes are of the following form:
<p-autoComplete
  inputId="myInput"
  class="p-fluid"
  [dropdown]="true"
  formControlName="myFormControl"
  (completeMethod)="filter($event.query)"
  [suggestions]="suggestions"
  [forceSelection]="true"
  [showClear]="true"
  (onClear)="myFormControl.reset()"
  appendTo="body">
</p-autoComplete>

This works as expected. However, when using the tab key to jump from one input to the next, it also focuses the "open dropdown" button. I would like to skip focussing this button and jump straight to the next input field.
I can't use [tabindex]="-1" on the p-autocomplete element because then it just skips the whole autocomplete input, but I only want to skip the dropdown button.
Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks.

There is no property that does this, you have to go for a custom directive to solve this!

There is no in-built property to do this, so you need to create a custom directive to do this. It would look something like below, where we find the button and update the tab index to -1 using renderer2 and elementRef
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[noButtonFocus]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class NoButtonFocusDirective {
  constructor(private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const dropdownButton = this.element.nativeElement.querySelector(
      '.p-autocomplete-dropdown'
    );
    if (dropdownButton) {
      this.renderer.setAttribute(dropdownButton, 'tabindex', '-1');
    }
  }
}

Parent Component:
<div class="card flex justify-content-center">
  <p-autoComplete
    noButtonFocus
    [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry"
    [dropdown]="true"
    [suggestions]="filteredCountries"
    (completeMethod)="filterCountry($event)"
    field="name"
  />
</div>

Stackblitz Demo
